# JS Calling Object Property by Variable

Tags: javascript, object

When I have an object and I want to refer to a property within it, I can use e.g.

```
objectName.propertyName
```

and when I have a "subproperty" I can use

```
objectName.propertyName.propertyName
```

But how can I use a variable with this syntax ?

```
objectName.myvar.propertyName
```

Obviously this does not work. The variable is interpreted as a string itself and calls for 
the value with the key: "myvar".

How do I have to declare the variable using this syntax to be used like this:

```
var myvar = qwertz; objectName.myvar.propertyName
```

and be interpreted as

```
var myvar = qwertz; objectName.qwertz.propertyName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties):

```
var myvar = 'qwertz';
var result = objectName[myvar].propertyName; 
// equivalent to objectName.qwertz.propertyName
```

Comment: Thx I didnt remove the dot between objectName and [myvar] when i used the brackets